# Bash script ignoring command on for loop

Tags: bash

I'm running a basic for loop bash script that logs into multiple linux boxes to execute a script and after the script logs out of every box, to wait 60 seconds. The problem is that the script is not applying the command within the script.

```
#!/bin/bash for i in `cat test.txt`;  do ssh -A -t -o userknownhostsfile=/dev/null -o stricthostkeychecking=no -o batchmode=yes -o connecttimeout=5 $i "sudo puppet agent -t & "; sleep 60; done
```

Comment: Is your script actually a one-liner like this this? That line is commented out... Also, are you able to run `sudo` on the remote machine without a password?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann You changed the OP's source code, which changes the question. That is extremely improper.

Comment: to remotely run sudo you may need two -t on your ssh options.  Probably you don't want -A (forward authentication)

Comment: @Vorsprung Im using -A to forward my private key for authentication.

Comment: @chrisaycock please see https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100066/room-for-micha-wiedenmann-and-chrisaycock

Comment: @jframone please respond to chrisaycock's question.

Comment: @chrisaycock Good point, i will leave the shebang on a separate line.. And yes i have root privileges on all the boxes that im logging in with my private ssh key.

Comment: I just broke it down into multiple lines and still same behavior

Comment: Is your user allowed to execute `puppet agent -t` on remote server without sudo password?

Comment: Yes i have root privileges to execute any command @Cyrus